# C controll secure dektop fails

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I created an app that controlls mouse and keyboard from remote computer (like InputDirector). Now i have the problem that i can not controll the secure desktop (lockscreen, UAC).
I read in other posts, i must use `SetThreadDesktop()`. But for me that do not work. Following is my code snipped how i renew the desktop (i use `SetCursorPos` to check if works in UAC):

```
if(flag_start_desk)
        {
            flag_start_desk = 0;
            POINT pt = { 0 };
            if(!GetCursorPos(&pt)) erz_output(red, LOCAL_FUNCTION_NAME, "Something went wrong to get mouse position\r\n");
            else SetCursorPos(pt.x-20, pt.y-20);

            if( (desk = OpenInputDesktop(0, 0, WRITE_OWNER) ) == NULL) 
            { 
                erz_output(red, LOCAL_FUNCTION_NAME, "OID Error: %lu\r\n", GetLastError()); 
                Beep(530, 500); 
            }
            else
            {
                erz_output(green, LOCAL_FUNCTION_NAME, "New Desktop: %llu\r\n", desk);
                if( SetThreadDesktop(desk) == 0 )
                {
                    erz_output(red, LOCAL_FUNCTION_NAME, "STD Error: %lu\r\n", GetLastError());
                    Beep(530, 500);
                }
                //CloseDesktop(desk);
                //desk = NULL;
            }
        }
```

- When i call the function as normal user, the function works (cursor moves). When i start UAC i get the message `OID Error: 5` (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED).
- When i call the function as admin, I get `STD Error: 170` (ERROR_BUSY) on normal desktop. When i start UAC i get the message `OID Error: 5`.
- I also changed the `OpenInputDesktop(0, 0, WRITE_OWNER)` to `OpenInputDesktop(DF_ALLOWOTHERACCOUNTHOOK, 1, WRITE_OWNER)` with same result.
- Like other remote softwares, i create an app manifest with `uiAccess="true"` and add a digital certificate to the application. The result is the same as above, except for i do not need to start as admin.
- I also build an Service to try to controll the desktop / secure desktop but this seems do not work with `SetCursorPos`.
- A other post says, use `CreateProcessAsUser()` to start a child process witch controlls the secure desktop. The result is the same as above. But i will share my snipped also.

Call child:

```
int loadp(void) 
{
    DWORD sessionID = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
    HANDLE hToken;
    WTSQueryUserToken(sessionID, &hToken);

    // userdata for CreateProcessAsUser
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    // get secure desktop
    si.lpDesktop = ("winsta0\\default"); // default-Desktop

    // child app to start
    CHAR appPath[1024];
    memcpy(appPath, ("C:\\MinGW64\\bin\\proj\\TESTS\\client.exe"), 37);

    // start process witch can access secure desktop
    if (CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, appPath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    } else {
        printf(("Cannot start process: %d\n"), GetLastError());
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);

    return 0;
}
```

It feels like I'm going around in circles, maybe you can help me.
My goal is to abort or accept UAC popups and login on lockscreen.
I work on Windows 10.

Comment: OT:  No idea about the code.  As for UAC, these settings are configurable on your workstation.  So, please ensure that the settings are configured correctly for your expectations of a successful test of your app.  Just something that occurred to me ...

Comment: The calling process must have an associated window station. Does it have?

Comment: What did you mean? It have an default console window

Comment: @Erz The interactive window station is the only window station that can display a user interface or receive user input.  See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winstation/window-stations.

Comment: @Erz There are three standard desktops for each window station: the Winlogon desktop (Ctrl+Alt+Delete), the screen saver desktop, and the interactive desktop (explorer or any processes that are initiated by an interactive user). Also, the method of specifying which window station and desktop the process is associated with through the `lpDesktop` member of the `STARTUPINFO` structure is correct.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT  ok, but what is then the correct way? I understand your comment but not what to do.

Comment: @Erz In short, you should use `CreateDesktopA` to create a virtual desktop in order to proceed.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT now i tryed ``CreateDesktopA``. My result is a new desktop without any content. Only the default accent color shows.
I testet some sequences with ``CreateDesktopA``, ``CreateProcessAsUser`` and  ``SetThreadDesktop`` but i found no way. What do i wrong?

Comment: @Erz Check this sample: https://gist.github.com/Torrecto/e2568e85bda26e025f7198a1497d3571

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT thank you for your code. Did you call the application as admin or from ``CreateProcessAsUser``?
I created yesterday an similar code but without success

Comment: @Erz I'm not there so far. Actually, I'm not so familiar with it. I'll spend my time on keeping testing.

Comment: @Erz I posted an asnwer. Check if it is what your need.

Comment: I did [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2822292/179634) quite some time ago, but that was on Windows 7. It wouldn't surprise me if Microsoft made it more difficult to do on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

In the former sample,

- we used `GetThreadDesktop` to get the default active desktop set by
  the system for that thread.
- Then used `SetThreadDesktop` to set the desktop associated with this
  thread to the desktop we created by `CreateDeskTop`.

We can switch and close the desktops in our windows station. Now,

1. Pay attention, not the previous creation process, there is a setting for the lpDesktop option. We will set it to create process for our new desktop.

---

```
#define DESTOP_NAME  L"MY_DESTOP"
        hDDesk = CreateDesktop(
                        DESTOP_NAME,
                        0, 0, 0,
                        GENERIC_ALL,
                        NULL
                    );
        STARTUPINFO sti = 
                    {
                        sizeof(sti)
                    };
        sti.lpDesktop =(LPWSTR)DESTOP_NAME;
```

Please refer to [Thread Connection to a Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winstation/thread-connection-to-a-desktop). Need to note, *The desktop assigned during this connection process cannot be closed by calling the CloseDesktop function.*

2. Then, we can create process for the new desktop. Before it we need
   to    determines whether the specified process is running under
   WOW64 or an    Intel64 of x64 processor.

---

```
typedef BOOL(__stdcall* P_IsWow64Process)(HANDLE, BOOL*);
HMODULE _Kernel32 = GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll");
if (_Kernel32 == 0)
{
    return FALSE;
}
P_IsWow64Process iswow64process = (P_IsWow64Process)GetProcAddress(_Kernel32, "IsWow64Process");
int bwow64 = 0;
iswow64process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bwow64);
```

3. As you wish, We can create windows in two desktops and Register
   HotKey to control cursor by processing input from the arrow keys. Here I made sample which used F6 to switch to current desktop, F7 switch to new created desktop. F8 back to current desktop and close the new one.
   [Using the Keyboard to Move the Cursor.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-cursors#using-the-keyboard-to-move-the-cursor)

Tips:

- Window will display on desktop created by CreateDesktop When it is
  created after `CreateDesktop` .
- Before using `CloseDeskTop`, you must switch back to current desktop.
  Otherwise, you will never get back.
- You cannot use the feature ALT+TAb switching desktop after a desktop
  name was specified in the lpDesktop member of the STARTUPINFO
  structure.Unless restart the PC.
- Please run as an adminstrator.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<windows.h>
 
TCHAR szAppName[] = L"TEST";
#define DESTOP_NAME  L"MY_DESTOP"   

ATOM m_HotKeyId1;
ATOM m_HotKeyId2;
ATOM m_HotKeyId3;
HDESK hDDesk;
HDESK hOld;
//HWINSTA  hWinStaThisProcess = GetProcessWindowStation();  
//HDESK hDeskOriignInput = OpenInputDesktop(0, FALSE, GENERIC_ALL); 
void OnHotKey(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static LRESULT lRes = 0;

    if (wParam == m_HotKeyId1)
    {
        
        SwitchDesktop(hOld);
    }
    else if (wParam == m_HotKeyId2)
    {
        SwitchDesktop(hDDesk);
    }
    else if (wParam == m_HotKeyId3)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"quit", L"caution", 0);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        SwitchDesktop(hOld);
        BOOL res=CloseDesktop(hDDesk);
        MessageBox(0, L"failed", L"closed", 0);
    }
    return ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

    POINT p;
    ClientToScreen(hwnd, &p);

    RECT winrect;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &winrect);
//hotkey
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_HOTKEY:
        OnHotKey(wParam, lParam);
        return 0;
    }

//cursor
    HCURSOR hCurs1, hCurs2;    // cursor handles 

    POINT pt;                  // cursor location  
    RECT rc;                   // client area coordinates 
    static int repeat = 100;     // repeat key counter 
    // 
    // Other declarations and initialization. 
    // 
    switch (message)
    {
        // 
        // Process other messages. 
        // 
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (wParam != VK_LEFT && wParam != VK_RIGHT &&
            wParam != VK_UP && wParam != VK_DOWN)
        {
            break;
        }
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        // Convert screen coordinates to client coordinates. 
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);  
        switch (wParam)
        {
            // Move the cursor to reflect which 
            // arrow keys are pressed. 
        case VK_LEFT:               // left arrow 
            pt.x -= repeat;
            break;

        case VK_RIGHT:              // right arrow 
            pt.x += repeat;
            break;

        case VK_UP:                 // up arrow 
            pt.y -= repeat;
            break;

        case VK_DOWN:               // down arrow 
            pt.y += repeat;
            break;

        default:
            return 0;
        }
        repeat++;           // Increment repeat count. 
        // Keep the cursor in the client area. 
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        
        if (pt.x >= rc.right)
        {
            pt.x = rc.right - 100;
        }
        else
        {
            if (pt.x < rc.left)
            {
                pt.x = rc.left;
            }
        }
        if (pt.y >= rc.bottom)
            pt.y = rc.bottom - 100;
        else
            if (pt.y < rc.top)
                pt.y = rc.top;
        // Convert client coordinates to screen coordinates. 
        ClientToScreen(hwnd, &pt);
        SetCursorPos(pt.x, pt.y);
        return 0;
    case WM_KEYUP:
        repeat = 10;            // Clear repeat count. 
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    hOld = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());

    int result = 0;
    typedef BOOL(__stdcall* P_IsWow64Process)(HANDLE, BOOL*);
    HMODULE _Kernel32 = GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll");
    if (_Kernel32 == 0)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    P_IsWow64Process iswow64process = (P_IsWow64Process)GetProcAddress(_Kernel32, "IsWow64Process");

    HWND hwnd;
    HWND hwnd2;
    MSG  msg;
    WNDCLASS    wndclass;

    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;

    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"RegisterClass failed!", NULL, 0);
        return 0;
    }
    hwnd = CreateWindow(
        szAppName, szAppName,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        0, 0,
        800, 600,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL
    );
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);

    hDDesk = CreateDesktop(
        DESTOP_NAME,
        0, 0, 0,
        GENERIC_ALL,
        NULL
    );
    result = SetThreadDesktop(hDDesk);

    STARTUPINFO sti = {
        sizeof(sti)
    };
    sti.lpDesktop =(LPWSTR)DESTOP_NAME;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };

    int bwow64 = 0;
    iswow64process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bwow64);
    if (bwow64)
    {
        result = CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\explorer.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sti, &pi);
    }
    else {
        result = CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sti, &pi);
    }

    if (result)
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }

    m_HotKeyId1 = GlobalAddAtomW(L"HotKey1") - 0xc000;
    RegisterHotKey(hwnd, m_HotKeyId1, 0, VK_F6);

    m_HotKeyId2 = GlobalAddAtomW(L"HotKey2") - 0xc000;
    RegisterHotKey(hwnd, m_HotKeyId2, 0, VK_F7);

    m_HotKeyId3 = GlobalAddAtomW(L"HotKey3") - 0xc000;
    RegisterHotKey(hwnd, m_HotKeyId3, MOD_CONTROL | MOD_SHIFT, VK_F8);

    RegisterHotKey(hwnd, m_HotKeyId3, 0, VK_F8);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    UnregisterHotKey(hwnd, m_HotKeyId1);
    GlobalDeleteAtom(m_HotKeyId1);

    UnregisterHotKey(hwnd, m_HotKeyId2);
    GlobalDeleteAtom(m_HotKeyId2);

    UnregisterHotKey(hwnd, m_HotKeyId3);
    GlobalDeleteAtom(m_HotKeyId3);


    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your work and spending time on my question!
When i run your app as administrator, a gui and console opened. In the gui i can controll the cursor with the arrow keys as you described.  
With the F-Hotkeys i can switch to the new desktop or back.
But i do not understand how does this solve my question, when i lock the new desktop with WIN+L, i cant use the hotkeys or arrow keys to do anything, same for an UAC propmt.  
Can  you please explain what your example should do for controlling the secure desktop?

Comment: @Erz Wow. That's not easy. It requires you to obtain the access of SYSTEM not just admin. You can see this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56595640/sendinput-fails-on-uac-prompt?noredirect=1&lq=1 
I'll try making it. But it will take a lot of time. Is that urgent for you?

Comment: my example in the start post based on the example in your link.
No, i have time and have already invested a lot of time :D

Comment: @Erz I'm sorry to bring the bad news. I tried to obtain the access but failed. In the former version like win 7, I can use superCMD to obtain access of SYSTEM. It not cannot run in win10: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYBXo.png. Actually, I finished the code: https://gist.github.com/Torrecto/40e0b077f9526e5121fc99a83e6e4464, But it's all for nothing without access of SYSTEM: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARF0x.png Right now, Microsoft is not open the access of SYSTEM. Maybe there is some "grey" ways to get it. I do not suggest to use that. It may destroy your system.

Comment: In other words, this proposed answer doesn't actually answer the question.